# Index of string value in MiniZinc array

Tags: constraints, minizinc

### The question

Given a MiniZinc array of strings:

```
int: numStats;
set of int: Stats = 1..numStats;
array[Stats] of string: statNames;
```

... with data loaded from a MiniZinc data file:

```
numStats = 3;
statNames = ["HEALTH", "ARMOR", "MANA"];
```

How can one look up the index of a specific string in the array? For example, that ARMOR is located at position 2.

### The context

I need to find an optimal selection of items with regard to some constraints on their stats. This information is stored in a 2D array declared as follows:

```
int: numItems;
set of int: Items = 1..numItems;
array[Items, Stats] of float: itemStats;
```

So in order to write a constraint on, say, the minimum amount of ARMOR obtained through the selected items, I need to know that ARMOR has index 2 in the inner array.

Since the data file is generated by an external program, and the number and order of stats are dynamic, I cannot hardcode the indices in the constraints.

### One solution (that won't work in my case)

The [MiniZinc tutorial](https://www.minizinc.org/downloads/doc-latest/minizinc-tute.pdf) uses an interesting trick to achieve something similar:

```
set of int: Colors = 1..3;
int: red = 1;
int: yellow = 2;
int: blue = 3;
array[Colors] of string: name = ["red", "yellow", "blue"];

var Colors: x;
constraint x != red;
output [ name[fix(x)] ];
```

Unfortunately, as variable declarations are not allowed in MiniZinc data files, this trick won't work in my case.

Answer (score 5):

You can write your own *custom function* to get the index of a string within a string array:

```
function int: getIndexOfString(string: str, 
                               array[int] of string: string_array) = 
   sum(  [ if str = string_array[i] 
              then i
           else 0 endif  
          | i in index_set(string_array) ]
   );
```

In this function I create an array of integers where the integer at position `i` either equals the index of `str` if `string_array[i]=str` and  `0` otherwise. For instance, for your sample string array `["HEALTH", "ARMOR", "MANA"]` and str `ARMOR` the resulting int array will be `[0,2,0]`.

This is why I can simply sum over the int array to get the index of the string. If the string does not occur, the return value is `0`, which is fine since indices in MiniZinc start with 1 by default.

Here is how you can call the function above for your first example:

```
int: numStats;
set of int: Stats = 1..numStats;
array[Stats] of string: statNames;

numStats = 3;
statNames = ["HEALTH", "ARMOR", "MANA"];

var int: indexOfArmor;

constraint 
   indexOfArmor = getIndexOfString("ARMOR",statNames);  

solve satisfy;
```

Note however that the function above is limited and has some flaws. First, if you have multiple occurrences of the string in the array, then you will receive an invalid index (the sum of all indices where `str` occurred). Also, if you have your own index set for your string array (say `(2..6)`), then you will need to adapt the function.

Comment: That is a clever hack! I will give this a try the next time I spend some time on the project. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Another, cleaner option is to write a function that uses a recursive helper function:

```
% main function
function int: index_of(string: elem, array[int] of string: elements) =
      let {
        int: index = length(elements);
      } in    % calls the helper function with the last index
        get_index(elem, elements, index)
; 

% recursive helper function    
function int: get_index(string: elem, array[int] of string: elements, int: index) = 
    if index == 0 
        then -1  % the element was not found (base case of recursion)
    elseif elements[index] == elem 
        then index % the element was found
    else 
        get_index(elem, elements, index - 1) % continue searching
    endif  
;
```

The helper function iterates recursively over the array, starting from the last element, and when it finds the element, it returns the index. If the element was not found in the array, then `-1` is returned. Alternatively, you can also throw an assertion following the suggestion of [Patrick Trentin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6024122/patrick-trentin) by replacing `then -1` with `then assert(false, "unknown element: " + elem)`.

An example of calling this function:

```
set of int: Customers =  1..5;
array[Customers] of string: ids = ["a-1", "a-2", "a-3", "a-4", "a-5"];

var int: index = index_of("a-3", ids); 
var int: unknown_index = index_of("x-3", ids);
```

where `index` will be assigned `3` and `unknown_index` will be `-1`.

Comment: Thank you! It looks cleaner indeed. It's interesting to learn about the many ways of doing this. Unfortunately, I can't test this on my project right now, because floating point support seems pretty broken in recent versions of MiniZinc, at least when I try with the built-in solvers in the MiniZinc IDE. Since my project uses a lot of floats, I can't run my model right now :(. Once I get a working setup again, I will give this solution a try.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach to that presented by [Andrea Rendl-Pitrey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8230870/andrea-rendl-pitrey), is the following one:

```
array[int] of string: statNames = array1d(10..12, ["HEALTH", "ARMOR", "MANA"]);

var int: indexOfArmor =
    sum([i | i in index_set(statNames) where statNames[i] = "ARMOR"]);

solve satisfy;  

output [
   "indexOfArmor=", show(indexOfArmor), "\n",
];
```

which outputs:

```
~$ mzn2fzn example.mzn ; flatzinc example.fzn
indexOfArmor = 11;
----------
```

***note:*** that `var` can be dropped from the declaration of `indexOfArmor`, since the index can be statically computed. I kept it here only for output purposes.

---

A better solution is to declare a new `predicate`:

```
predicate index_of_str_in_array(var int: idx, 
                                string: str,
                                array[int] of string: arr) =
    assert(
        not exists(i in index_set(arr), j in index_set(arr))
                  (i != j /\ arr[i] = str /\ arr[j] = str), 
        "input string occurs at multiple locations",
    assert(
        exists(i in index_set(arr))
              (arr[i] = str),
        "input string does not occur in the input array",

        exists(i in index_set(arr))
              (arr[i] = str /\ i = idx)
    ));
```

which enforces both of the following conditions:

- `str` occurs at least once in `arr`
- `str` does not occur multiple times in `arr`

**e.g**

```
predicate index_of_str_in_array(var int: idx,
                                string: str,
                                array[int] of string: arr) =
            ...

array[10..13] of string: statNames =
                 array1d(10..13, ["HEALTH", "ARMOR", "MANA", "ATTACK"]);

var int: indexOfArmor;

constraint index_of_str_in_array(indexOfArmor, "ARMOR", statNames);

solve satisfy;  

output [
   "indexOfArmor=", show(indexOfArmor), "\n",
];
```

outputs

```
~$ mzn2fzn example.mzn ; flatzinc example.fzn
indexOfArmor = 11;
----------
```

If one changes `statNames` in the following way

```
array[10..13] of string: statNames =
                 array1d(10..13, ["HEALTH", "ARMOR", "MANA", "ARMOR"]);
```

then  `mzn2fzn` detects an *assertion violation*:

```
~$ mzn2fzn example.mzn ; flatzinc example.fzn
MiniZinc: evaluation error: 
  example.mzn:24:
  in call 'index_of_str_in_array'
  example.mzn:4:
  in call 'assert'
  Assertion failed: input string occurs at multiple locations
flatzinc:
  example.fzn: cannot open input file: No such file
```

A similar result would be obtained by searching for the index of a string that does not occur in the array. This condition can of course be removed if not necessary.

---

**DISCLAIMER:** older versions of `mzn2fzn` don't seem to check that the declared `index-set` of an `array of strings` variable matches the `index-set` of an `array of strings literal` that is being assigned to it. This rule is enforced on newer versions, as it is also valid for other data types.

Comment: Thanks! I will give this solution a try as well. Looks like it might be a slightly cleaner hack!

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33985298/minizinc-constraint-solving-with-large-string-data) other post on Stackoverflow there is no way of converting strings to integers in MiniZinc, only the other way around. You need to first pre process your data in some other language and turn it into integers. You can however turn those integers into string once you are done in MiniZinc.

You can however load MiniZinc files instead of data files if you would like. Use the include syntax to include any .mzn file.

Comment: Your idea about including another .mzn file is nice. I realized that after posting my question as well, and it is what I have been doing in the meantime.