# How to find the index of an element in an int array? - MiniZinc

Tags: arrays, minizinc

Does MiniZinc have a built-in method equivalent to the indexOf() method in Java / index() method in Python?

Answer (score 1):

No, to the best of my knowledge and according to the [MiniZinc specification](https://www.minizinc.org/doc-2.2.3/en/spec.html#array-operations) there is no built-in function for `indexOf()`. You will have to write your own function for that, for instance following along the line of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35758640/index-of-string-value-in-minizinc-array/).

Answer (score 0):

One solution:

constraint forall(position in POSITIONS,v in VALUES where var[position]=v)(...)